# reduce typescript on a databse entity

Tags: typescript, reduce

I have a Food entity which has a price column

Somewhere in project, I have an array of foods and I want to extract the sum of their prices using `reduce()` method to make the code more compact. However, I get the error where it says: `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Food'` and `The expected type comes from the return type of this signature` for each element is the reduce function. this is not an issue when I use a for loop, but I want to use a reduce method to make the code easier to read.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to type your initial value of reduce (the second argument). If you share  code minimum reproducable example and pleace where you getting an error, I will try to help

Comment: @captain-yossarian
```typescript
const totalAmount = foods.reduce((food1,food2)=>food1.price+food2.price)
```
and the error happens on food1.price and food2.price

Comment: also I can do it with a map first and then a reduce on the mapped prices, but I was wondering is there a way to do all of it with one reduce

Answer (score 1):

first of all, it is always Ok to ask the questions.
There is no wrong questions.

Here is the piece of code which might help you.

```js
type Food = {
    price: number
}
const foods = [
    { price: 10 },
    { price: 20 }
]
const totalAmount = foods.reduce((food1, food2) => {
    return {
        price: food1.price + food2.price
    }
}, { price: 0 })
totalAmount // {price: 30}
```

You forgot to define second argument of `reduce` function.
Also you can return just the number:

```js
type Food = {
    price: number
}
const foods = [
    { price: 10 },
    { price: 20 }
]
const totalAmount = foods.reduce((total, food) => total + food.price, 0)
```

Also I don't think you should remove your question. It might help other people. That's why stackoverflow is so popular